# ¿Que configuración de DNS conviene más para un registro tipo MX en DNS externo?

Tags: email, servidor, dns

¿Que configuración de DNS conviene más para un registro tipo MX en DNS externo?

1. Tener un sólo registro tipo MX `mx.domain.com`. resolviendo a dos registros tipo A:

   ```
   MX  10  mail.domain.com.    ->  A   1.2.3.4
                               ->  A   1.2.3.5
   ```

Ó

2. Tener dos registros tipo MX `mx1.domain.com`. `mx2.domain.com`. resolviendo a registros tipo A con direcciones IP distintas.

   ```
   MX  10  mx1.domain.com. ->  A   ->  1.2.3.4
   MX  20  mx2.domain.com. ->  A   ->  1.2.3.5
   ```

Actualmente se tienen 2 servidores de DNS y dos servidores de Mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asumo que tenés 2 servidores de mail, y que la intención es aprovecharlos para aumentar la confiabilidad (es decir, asegurarte que si un servidor está caído, el otro procese tus mails entrantes)

## TL;DR

Si lo que querés maximizar es la confiabilidad, lo que te conviene sin dudas es la opción 2.

## Por qué?

Los registros `MX` son usados por los otros servidores de mail, cuando un usuario les pide enviar un mail a `reynaldo@domain.com`. Para saber a qué servidor lo tienen que enviar, hacen una consulta `MX` a los DNS de `domain.com`.

Cuando hay una entrada DNS a varios `MX`s, el servidor aplica [DNS Round Robin](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dns_round_robin), desordenándolos en cada respuesta. La clave es que las entradas DNS son cacheadas en varios niveles (por los DNS locales, por los OSs) para hacer todo más rápido.

Entonces... yo, `g3rv4@gmail.com` quiero mandarte un mail a `reynaldo@domain.com`. Al mandarlo, mi pedido lo atiende `servidor1.gmail.com`. Como `servidor1.gmail.com` no sabe a qué servidor tiene que reenviar el mail, hace una consulta DNS pidiendo por los `MX` de `domain.com`

Si tu zona es esta

```
MX  10  mail.domain.com.    ->  A   1.2.3.4
                            ->  A   1.2.3.5
```

Entonces va a recibir `mail.domain.com`, y cuando pregunte por `mail.domain.com`, va a recibir `1.2.3.4` y `1.2.3.5`... pero lo interesante es que va a elegir una `IP` Y LA VA A CACHEAR. Entonces, si eligió `1.2.3.4` y justo ese servidor está caído, no va a poder rutear el mail y listo. Además, mientras no invalide el caché, no va a intentar con `1.2.3.5`... y una vez que lo invalide, necesitás tener la suerte de que `1.2.3.5` venga primero :)

Mientras que si hacés

```
MX  10  mx1.domain.com. ->  A   ->  1.2.3.4
MX  20  mx2.domain.com. ->  A   ->  1.2.3.5
```

Cuando `servidor1.gmail.com` hace una consulta por los `MX` de `domain.com`, recibe `mx1.domain.com` Y `mx2.domain.com`. También sabe que `mx1.domain.com` es el preferido (porque tiene prioridad 10, que es más alta que 20) y si `mx1.domain.com` está caído, entonces va a reintentar con `mx2.domain.com`.

Esta es *la forma* de configurar los registros `MX` (por eso [es lo que usa Google en G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=es))

Comment: Muchas gracias por tú excelente explicación, no tenia en cuenta la parte del CACHE muy buena observación, otra pregunta ¿En caso de tener los servidores de correo mx1.domain.com. 1.2.3.4 y mx2.domain.com. 1.2.3.5 lo ideal sería tenerlos como Activo-Activo por llamarlos de alguna manera ambos dando servicio de manera pareja, recomendarías tener la misma prioridad es decir MX 10 para ambos nodos y así tenerlos trabajando al %50-%50 para optimizar los recursos o cual sería la recomendación y por qué?, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si te da lo mismo que los mails los atienda uno u otro, entonces tiene sentido que le pongas la misma prioridad a lost dos. Sólo tienen que tener distintas prioridades si preferís que los mails los atienda uno. El número de prioridad no importa, pueden ser los dos 10, 1, 50 o 100. Lo que importa es la relación entre ellos ;)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo si tu proyecto es simple  en este caso usar un solo registro dns para el mx. Esta recomendacion la hago ya que no has especificado o añadido algún detalle de tu proyecto o alguna problematica para decidir si se requiere de multiples mx.

Comment: en qué caso un proyecto "requiere de múltiples mx"? cómo se mide la complejidad de la administración de emails? cómo afecta esta complejidad a la cantidad de servidores mx.

Comment: Hola @g3rv4 el mecanismo MX permite usar múltiples servidores de emails para un solo dominio y establece el orden en el cual deberían ser interrogados estos servidores. Se mide la complejidad cuando desde tu servidor de correo necesitas dividir las gestiones en multiples servidores debido a un aumento considerable de tráfico o por que has experimentado algún problema de performance. También puede ser por que decidiste que estos servidores crezcan horizontalmente. Espero que sea de tu ayuda mi respuesta.

Comment: gracias Hugo por la respuesta :) como no estoy del todo de acuerdo, escribí la mía! leela y contame si estás en desacuerdo... tengo tanto para aprender!

Comment: Hola @g3rv4 gracias por tu respuesta tan completa, estoy totalmente de acuerdo, además la he puntuado positivamente, me gustaría que me indiques en que no estas de acuerdo con mi respuesta. Un gran saludo

Comment: Antes que todo, me gusta muchísimo poder disentir sintiendo que estamos conversando como gente normal y no como gente que se pone a pelear atrás de un monitor :) estoy en desacuerdo con tu sugerencia de usar un solo MX. Si tiene dos, al usar uno está perdiendo confiabilidad (ya que si *ese* se cae, los mails no van a llegar). En toda circunstancia conviene usar los dos, independientemente del proyecto.

Comment: @g3rv4 si, no hay problemas y una vez más estás en lo correcto, al tener dos registros MX estás teniendo un servidor con características de alta disponibilidad lo que es mejor y mucho más eficiente. Necesito aclarar que dentro de infraestructura tenemos varias maneras de proceder y mucho depende de donde esté montada la infraestructura, presupuesto y otras variables externas, creo que estuvo bien que asumas que tiene dos servidores para completar mejor tu respuesta y así enseñar el camino más complejo, un gran saludo ;)

Comment: Buenas tardes a todos, muchas gracias por su gentíl apoyo, sí cuento con dos servidores de correo: Tengo un sólo registro MX mail.ejemplo.com. que resuelve a dos registros tipo A 1.1.1.1 y 2.2.2.2, el detalle justamente es ver las ventajas y/o desventajas que esto conlleva, por que actualmente administro un DNS y observo esta configuración,  'Number of MX records  OK. Looks like you only have one MX record at your nameservers but that MX record has multiple IPs. You should be careful about what you are doing but overall it's ok.', con base en mi infraestruc, ¿Cuál sería la mejor configuración?